# Is there a way to fix push notification for ios 10 using xcode 7.3.1 and swift 2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios10

I am not able to get device token in iOS 10 devices and the fix for this is to use Xcode 8.0 and use new framework(UserNotifications.framework) for ios push notification.

So , is there a way to fix it by staying on xcode 7.3.1 ?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: I fixed it by moving to xcode 8.